# How to obtain value of textbox within jQuery Mobile Listview control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is hopefully an easy question, but I'm getting the suspicion my design might need some more thought.  I have a [Listview](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/listview/) control like such:

```
<ul id="txtTo" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="To:"></ul>
```

Since the `data-filter` property is `true`, the control creates a textbox for filtering:

[image]

I need to know how to obtain the value of that textbox.  I've tried both `$("#txtTo").val()` and `$("#txtTo").text()` but both return `""`.

Nothing in the docs seem to indicate how to obtain the current filter value, and I've dug through the properties in the Chrome debugger to no avail.  Any ideas?

I have a sinking suspicion the answer is to use my own `<input>`, listen to whenever the value changes, and update a separate `listview` control instead and not use `data-filter`.

Comment: you can use the F12 developer tools to find what the element looks like in the HTML to determine if you're selecting the correct element or if the jQuery control is doing something you didn't expect

Comment: Yup, spent about 20 minutes doing that.  I think the `listview` control simply doesn't expose its `input` tag, at least not publicly.  It is available in some events.

Comment: Weird, that stinks. Sorry to suggest the obvious, but I find a lot of people tend not to start there. I'll look around for an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code

```html
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search">
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-filter="true">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
```

on the jQuery mobile site here:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/filterable/

Will this work for you? You set an input to the listview, so you can easily get the text or set the text. You just need to include a **data-input** attribute on your ul.

Comment: Yup, this is a good solution.  Since I was overriding the `filterablebeforefilter` event anyway, I just decided to trap the `keyup` event of the textbox and render the matches directly in the `<ul>` which also works.  Thanks for pointing out the `data-type="search"` property as well!